# what do you see in her anyway?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I think I heard this conversation an ESL podcast. Two people are talking about the girls they have romantic interests in.

One person said, 
"what do you see in her anyway. She's a little chubby."

Does the phrase 'see in someone' used here mean that find someone attractive, as in "how do you find her attractive"?

Comment: It should be "what" not "where."

Comment: "What do you see in her?" means "Why are you interested in her?" Same difference, as the poet said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, there's an unstated *that* phrase:

> What do you see in her **that you find attractive**?

It can be used in other situations, with different implicit phrases.

> You're eating at Nando's again? I don't know what you see in that place.
>   *I don't know what you see in that place **that causes you to eat there so often***
>
> You're listening to early Genesis? What do you see in it?
>   *What do you see in it **that makes it worth listening to**?*

(Yes, the expression is also used for things you don't see)

> I see you have a full collection of Police Academy. What do you see in those films?
>   *What do you see in those films **that makes it worth owning them, and thus presumably re-watching them frequently**?*

It generally expresses incredulity or scepticism.

Answer (score 2):

It is, as you have guessed, basically a short-hand for "what (positive/desirable/attractive) (features/attributes/qualities) do you see in (another person)?"  A few dictionaries have definitions of the phrasal verb "see in" including, for example, [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/see-in), if you want more detail.